# Frame Animation Not Running

Tags: java, android, xml, animation

I have tried every sample of code I can find that defines and runs a frame animation, but the ImageView never changes. The original Image in the ImageView stays.

EDIT:
After many days of trial and error, I ran the APK on my phone instead of the emulator.
It works on my phone, but for some reason it does not on the emulator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not exactly clear why you can't start animations from the onCreate thread, they need to be posted to whatever thread the handler of the view was created on.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.shell);
    view.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
    view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animation_frame);

    view.post(new Runnable(){

      public void run(){
        AnimationDrawable frameAnimation =  (AnimationDrawable) view.getBackground();
        frameAnimation.start();
      }
    });
   }
}
```

I have no idea why you need to do this but you do.

edit:Here is snippets from my working project should be everything you need...

in java in onCreate:

```
final ImageView image1 =  (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.coin1);
image1.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            AnimationDrawable ani = (AnimationDrawable) image1.getBackground();
            ani.start();
        }
    });
```

in xml layout:

```
        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/coin"
        android:id="@+id/coin1"/>
```

coin xml:

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/coin_spin_a" android:duration="100"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/coin_spin_b" android:duration="100"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/coin_spin_c" android:duration="100"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/coin_spin_d" android:duration="100"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/coin_spin_e" android:duration="100"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/coin_spin_f" android:duration="100"/>
</animation-list>
```

Comment: Using that code, I get the errors:  Line 14:The type new Runnable(){} must implement the inherited abstract method Runnable.run().   Line16: Syntax error on token "start", Identifier expected after this token.

Comment: @Miles O'Keefe sorry about that, fixed.

Comment: No errors this time, but the ImageView is remaining the same. If this code is working for you, could you upload a project with it working?

Comment: @Miles O'Keefe I can't post the entire project but I added all the relevant snippets you should be able to get it working with this let me know if you have issues.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with it some time as well. It is explained in android frame animation tutorial, but let's say with "small letters". Let me copy the answer from there:

> It's important to note that the start() method called on the AnimationDrawable cannot be called during the onCreate() method of your Activity, because the AnimationDrawable is not yet fully attached to the window. If you want to play the animation immediately, without requiring interaction, then you might want to call it from the onWindowFocusChanged() method in your Activity, which will get called when Android brings your window into focus.

It is at the very bottom of http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html#frame-animation

Comment: I followed that advice, but the Image remains the same. 
I added:
 TextView top = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.top);
         top.setText("Started");   

After frameAnimation.start(); to test that the listener was really being triggered.
The text was changed to "started", but the Image did not change.

Comment: As far as I see, it should work. Can you also set the animation drawable in onWindowFocusChanged() rather than onCreate? It should not  make a difference, but maybe... And copy your code again if it does not work still

Answer (score 0):

Want to add a comment to schwiz answer.

I was able to get it working from calling the Handler.post from a worker thread. Below is the sample.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Thread t;
    final ImageView activityIndicator;
    final AnimationDrawable animiDrawable;
    LinearLayout contentPlaceholder;

    contentPlaceholder = (LinearLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.content_placeholder);
    activityIndicator = new ImageView(this);
    contentPlaceholder.addView(activityIndicator);
    activityIndicator.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_activity_indicator_bar);
    animiDrawable = (AnimationDrawable)activityIndicator.getBackground();

    t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mCbt.mThreadHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    animiDrawable.start();
                }
            });
        };
    });
    t.start();
}
```